# Proving equivalence of two rev_append implementations

Tags: coq, proof, formal-verification

Disclaimer: This is **not** a homework question.

I am trying to implement my own version of `rev_append` in Coq, and then to prove that it is equivalent to the built in version. The following is my implementation.

```
Fixpoint my_rev_append (l1 l2 : list nat) : (list nat) * (list nat) :=
  match l1 with
  | nil => (l1, l2)
  | hd :: tl => my_rev_append tl (hd :: l2)
  end.
```

Then I tried to prove that it is equivalent to `rev_append`

```
Theorem my_rev_append_correct : forall (l1 l2 : list nat),
    my_rev_append l1 l2 = (nil, (rev_append l1 l2)).
Proof.
  intros l1 l2.
  induction l1.
  reflexivity.
```

And then I hit the following goal, which I do not see a way to move forward.

```
  IHl1 : my_rev_append l1 l2 = (nil, rev_append l1 l2)
  ============================
  my_rev_append (a :: l1) l2 = (nil, rev_append (a :: l1) l2)
```

It is not possible to use `IHl1`, because the RHS of the current subgoal is `(nil, rev_append (a :: l1) l2)`, which does not contain `(nil, rev_append l1 l2)`. I tried to run `simpl` tactic on it, but it didn't work, as `IHl1` is still not applicable.

I totally understand that I can prove this by changing the `| nil => (l1, l2)` line in `my_rev_append` into `| nil => l2`. However, are there any possibility to prove this theorem *without* changing the definition of `my_rev_append`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition has `l2` varying through the induction. Therefore, the proof of the theorem should also have `l2` varying through the induction. To do this, do not `intro`duce `l2` before starting the induction, leaving it in the goal. The inductive hypothesis, whose type is modeled on this goal, then allows you to pass a different value for it in the recursive case.

```
Theorem my_rev_append_correct : forall (l1 l2 : list nat), my_rev_append l1 l2 = (nil, rev_append l1 l2).
Proof.
  induction l1 as [ | x l1 rec]; intros l2.
  - reflexivity.
  - apply rec.
Qed.
```

Comment: Leaving (or putting back) hypothesis in the goal to get an induction hypothesis that is strong enough is a very common thing to do, so much that `induction` has a special syntax for it. Here you could do: `intros l1 l2. induction l1 in l2 |- *`, where `in` modifier generalizes the induction hypothesis with respect to the hypothesis you mention (here `l2`).